# OAuth redirect_uri opencart by facebook sdk4

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, opencart, facebook-php-sdk

am New to opencart 1.5.5.1 almost did all configuration to make the site have login facebook but no use.

```
Graph returned an error: Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request
```

I tried to play with url from my side nothing work as checked on internet like add slash after the link and so on

this is the requested site

> https://www.facebook.com/v2.4/dialog/oauth?client_id=4444&state=444444&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.0.0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmarkaforyou%2Fwholesale%2F%3Froute%3Dfacebook%2Ffacebook&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_location%2Cuser_hometown

this url redirected to my site

> http://localhost/markaforyou/wholesale/?route=facebook%2Ffacebook&code=AQAB3eJHlzqyopMX0SSxRvChkEmoRE6LtQfghd54634645vb6ybhfgbhfghdfghjfdgh
>   fgZAZdYe4ivu94IsPf36hrpyfq3K4uyi7dx50&state=69e8f620cdbcdfdf43185fba9b70dc43#*=*

is there any thing I must need to do in configuration

Comment: Maybe you need to test with real URL and not localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a problem with facebook sdk url clearer
in the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php 
change the line

$redirectUrl = FacebookUrlManipulator::removeParamsFromUrl($redirectUrl, ['state']);

with

$redirectUrl = substr($redirectUrl, 0,  strpos($redirectUrl, '&state'));

and all thing work perfectly